# I cant Attach C# Script to my Player?

Tags: unity

Every time I try to attach my C# Script to my Player, it gives me this error message:

> "Can't add script component 'Player' because the script class cannot be found. Make sure that there are no compile errors and that the file name and class name match."

Here is my script, just for good measures

```
using UnityEngine;

using System.Collections;

public class Player : MonoBehaviour 
{   
    public float speed = 50f;
    public float jumpPower = 150f;
    public bool grounded;
    private Rigidbody2D rb2d;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () 
    {
        rb2d = gameObject.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () 
    {

    }

    void FixedUpdate()
    {
        float h = Input.GetAxis ("Horizontal");
        rb2d.AddForce ((Vector2.right) * speed * h);
    }
}
```

I have no Idea how to fix that...

Anyway, I am using Unity Engine 5

EDIT: I HAVE FOUND THE ERROR. (I forgot to save the script XD)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because he just forgot to save.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The message basically says it all. Either the name of your class which in this case is "Player" is not exactly the same as the c# script file name. Check if the c# script is called "Player.cs". If not rename it to that. (Case sensitive!) If that wasn't the case or it didn't solve the problem you should check if you have any compiler errors and fix those first.